# Vim: move visual selection, not text, up & down lines

Tags: vim

If I have this line visually selected

```
Alpha <-- selected
Bravo
Charlie
```

is there a vim command to move the selected area down, *without adding to the original selection*?

```
Alpha
Bravo
Charlie <-- selected
```

hjkl key will only add lines to your selection. And I didn't see anything in visual's help doc that indicated it could be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will certainly do it:

<kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>

But it isn't really any different from canceling the original selection first:

<kbd>esc</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>

Or:

<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. I set vmap <c-j> jVV and vmap <c-k> kVV, so I can quickly move the selection up and down while in visual mode.

Comment: Cool tip, thanks.  Also works in visual block mode and moving selection left/right.

Answer (score 6):

In selection mode, you can use <kbd>o</kbd> (lowercase o) to swap between moving the top and bottom boundary. So you can do this without leaving selection mode using <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>.

Comment: +1 - This isn't even needed for the OP's use case, but your answer imparts knowledge that can be generally applied.

Comment: accepted lwburk's because, to me, it's more helpful to drop the selection and reselect in situations where you're scrolling in visual mode. But otherwise works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I understand your question, you would like to select Alpha and move it down. Let us say move Alpha under Charlie. You need to select Alpha in visual mode and then type : (colon) and type m 3. So your typing format should like **:m 3**. This means that move selected text to line 3. I hope this will be your question answer. Have a great day.

Comment: no, I want the text to stay the same and move just the visual selection up/down 1 line.